# Anti-aliased fonts in tkinter?

Tags: python, fonts, tkinter

Is there a way to get anti-aliased fonts in tkinter? If I increase the size of the default font like so:

```
default_font = tkFont.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
default_font.configure(size=32)
```

the text comes out jagged.

Here is some version information:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, May  6 2015, 09:33:48) 
>>> Tkinter.__version__
'$Revision: 81008 $
```

I am using Gentoo Linux and have Tk 8.5 installed (which i believe should support anti-aliased fonts):

```
$ equery l tk
[IP-] [  ] dev-lang/tk-8.5.17:0/8.5
```

EDIT: adding this full MWE to describe what I'm doing:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont
from ttk import *

root = Tk()
note = Notebook(root)

default_font = tkFont.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
default_font.configure(size=48)

tab1 = Frame(note)
tab2 = Frame(note)
Button(tab1, text='Exit', command=root.destroy).pack(padx=100, pady=100)

note.add(tab1, text = "Curvy Words")
note.add(tab2, text = "Aliased")
note.pack()
root.mainloop()
exit()
```

Comment: The Tkinter ttk/tile widgets support anti_aliased fonts https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html

Comment: @CurlyJoe I've updated with a MWE to describe what I'm doing. I've read that the tile widgets support anti-aliased fonts, but from what I can tell I'm using one of the new widgets, with tk 8.5 - what else am I missing to get anti-aliased fonts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to have been an issue with how tk was installed with gentoo. After adding truetype support by setting the use flag

For example, I added the line to /etc/portage/package.use

```
>=dev-lang/tk-8.5.17 truetype
```

And then remerged tk:

```
emerge -Na tk
```

Comment: This requires Tk to have been built with the right font support. `root.eval("tk::pkgconfig get fontsystem")` should return 'xft' if anti-aliasing support has been included (on X11 at least).

Comment: That is good to know as sometime some else will have a similar problem.  Also check out infinality in gentoo/portage.  Makes a noticeable difference here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about ttk, but do know that you use "style" to set the font-->ttk tutorial http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html  This looks fine on my Slackware box, but it uses anti-aliased by default.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import tkFont

root = Tk()

##default_font = tkFont.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
##default_font.configure(size=48)

f = tkFont.Font(family='helvetica', size=24)
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('.', font=f)

note = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(note)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(note)

note.add(tab1, text = "Curvy Words")
note.add(tab2, text = "Aliased")
note.pack()

ttk.Style().configure("TButton", padding=6, relief="flat",
                       background="white")

ttk.Button(tab1, text='Exit', command=root.destroy).pack(padx=100, pady=100)

root.mainloop()
```